# Union of two SQL queries and select top most row

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two queries in SQL and I'm doing a union on both of them. Once I get the result I need to select first row in descending order of date for a given unique ID. I tried with something like below but error keeps popping.

```
SELECT  
   *
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         ACCT_NBR, ACCT_BLK_1 AS BLK_CDE, BLK_RSN_1 AS BLK_CDE_RSN,
         BLK_CDE_1_CHG_DT AS CLOSED_DT
     FROM 
         TABLE_1 
     WHERE 
         ACCT_BLK_1,'@') IN ('A') 
         AND DATE = CURRENT_DATE - 1
         AND BLK_CDE_1_CHG_DT BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-10'

     UNION

     SELECT DISTINCT 
         ACCT_NBR, ACCT_BLK_2 AS BLK_CDE, BLK_RSN_2 AS BLK_CDE_RSN,
         BLK_CDE_2_CHG_DT AS CLOSED_DT
     FROM 
         TABLE_2 
     WHERE 
         ACCT_BLK_2,'@') IN ('A') 
         AND DATE = CURRENT_DATE - 1
         AND BLK_CDE_2_CHG_DT BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-10')
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCT_NBR ORDER BY CLOSED_DT) = 1
```

Comment: _"error keeps popping"_ ...come on. What error? [Edit] your post to quote it in full (not as a screenshot either).

Answer (score 2):

Of course, this `ACCT_BLK_1,'@') IN ('A')` is not valid syntax, probably a cut&paste issue.

There's no need to apply (UNION) DISTINCT when you want the top 1 row.

```
SELECT  
   *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ACCT_NBR, ACCT_BLK_1 AS BLK_CDE, BLK_RSN_1 AS BLK_CDE_RSN,
         BLK_CDE_1_CHG_DT AS CLOSED_DT
     FROM 
         TABLE_1 
     WHERE 
         ACCT_BLK_1,'@') IN ('A') -- fix syntax
         AND DATE = CURRENT_DATE - 1
         AND BLK_CDE_1_CHG_DT BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-10'

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         ACCT_NBR, ACCT_BLK_2 AS BLK_CDE, BLK_RSN_2 AS BLK_CDE_RSN,
         BLK_CDE_2_CHG_DT AS CLOSED_DT
     FROM 
         TABLE_2 
     WHERE 
         ACCT_BLK_2,'@') IN ('A') -- fix syntax
         AND DATE = CURRENT_DATE - 1
         AND BLK_CDE_2_CHG_DT BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-10'
    ) as dt -- the table alias was missing
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCT_NBR ORDER BY CLOSED_DT) = 1
```

Depending on the data it might be more efficient to apply QUALIFY before UNION:

```
SELECT  
   *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ACCT_NBR, ACCT_BLK_1 AS BLK_CDE, BLK_RSN_1 AS BLK_CDE_RSN,
         BLK_CDE_1_CHG_DT AS CLOSED_DT
     FROM 
         TABLE_1 
     WHERE 
         ACCT_BLK_1,'@') IN ('A') -- fix syntax
         AND DATE = CURRENT_DATE - 1
         AND BLK_CDE_1_CHG_DT BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-10'
      QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCT_NBR ORDER BY CLOSED_DT) = 1

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         ACCT_NBR, ACCT_BLK_2 AS BLK_CDE, BLK_RSN_2 AS BLK_CDE_RSN,
         BLK_CDE_2_CHG_DT AS CLOSED_DT
     FROM 
         TABLE_2 
     WHERE 
         ACCT_BLK_2,'@') IN ('A') -- fix syntax
         AND DATE = CURRENT_DATE - 1
         AND BLK_CDE_2_CHG_DT BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-10'
     QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCT_NBR ORDER BY CLOSED_DT) = 1
    ) as dt -- the table alias was missing
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCT_NBR ORDER BY CLOSED_DT) = 1
```